# How to create a new data structure in C++ with object orientation?

Tags: c++, mingw32

This semester in university I have a class called Data Structures, and the professor allowed the students to choose their favourite language. As I want to be a game programmer, and I can't take Java anymore, I chose C++ ... but now I'm stuck with lack of knowledge in this language. I have to do the following: create a SuperArray, which is like a Delphi array (you can choose the starting and ending index of it). My code is as follows:

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "SuperArray.h"    

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
    int start, end;
    cout << "Starting index" << endl;
    cin >> start;
    cout << "Ending index:" << endl;
    cin >> end;
    SuperArray array = new SuperArray(start,end); 
}
```

superarray.h

```
#ifndef _SUPERARRAY_H
#define _SUPERARRAY_H

class SuperArray
{
public:
    SuperArray(int start, int end);
    void add(int index,int value);
    int get(int index);
    int getLength();
private:
    int start, end, length;
    int *array;

};

#endif  /* _SUPERARRAY_H */
```

superarray.cpp

```
#include "SuperArray.h"

SuperArray::SuperArray(int start, int end)
{
    if(start < end)
    {
        this->start = start;
        this->end = end;
        this->length = (end - start) + 1;
        this->array = new int[this->length];
    }
}

void SuperArray::add(int index, int value)
{
    this->array[index-this->start] = value;
}

int SuperArray::get(int index)
{
    return this->array[index-this->start];
}
```

When I try to compile this code, I have the following error:

```
error: conversion from `SuperArray*' to non-scalar type `SuperArray' requested
```

What should I do?

Comment: object orientation vs object oriented?

Comment: Keep in mind that for every 'new' you must also write a 'delete'. And don't forget to implement a copy constructor, or make your class noncopyable.

Comment: Don't you think you're putting undue pressure on yourself to learn a new language while doing this?  I mean, if someone asked me to write a book in any language, I'd pick a language I knew.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unlike Java, in C++ you don't *need* to use the `new` keyword to create objects. In Java, all objects are stored on the heap (free store) and can only be accessed via references.

In C++, objects can be value types. You can declare them directly on the stack, e.g.

```
SuperArray array(start, end);
```

And you can call methods like:

```
array.get(1);
```

This object will be automatically destroyed when `array` goes out of scope. If you want to manage the lifetime of the `array` object manually, you can *optionally* create it on the heap using `new`, but then you have to refer to it with a pointer:

```
SuperArray* array = new SuperArray(start, end);
```

Now, you must call methods like this:

```
array->get(i);
```

since `array` in this case is a pointer to a `SuperArray` and not a `SuperArray` itself (and a pointer has no `get` method of its own). The `->` operator means to use the `.` operator on the pointed-to object.

In this case, the object pointed to by the `array` pointer will continue to exist until you call `delete array;` If you fail to explicitly delete the object, it will never be deallocated (C++ has no garbage collector!) and you will have a memory leak.

Note that C++ has things called "pointers" and things called "references". A Java "reference" has some of the properties of both of these things and is not directly equivalent to either. A good introductory text on C++ should explain the difference between these.

Answer (score 1):

`array` should be a pointer to be allocated on the heap. Change its definition to:

```
SuperArray* array = new SuperArray(start,end);
```

You can get rid of the pointer by allocating the array on the local stack:

```
SuperArray array(start,end);
```

A stack object is enough if you don't intend to pass share the object across modules.

Comment: Should explain why they're different!

Answer (score 1):

At least as a starting point (and probably permanently, unless the prof made me change it) I'd use an `std::vector` to manage the storage, and just write a front-end that manages the offsets to the indices as needed.

Edit: if I was forced to change that, I'd still study `std::vector`'s interface, and imitate it as much as possible, so nearly the only change would be the (possibly) non-zero lower bound on the index. I'd also study how it manages memory, and imitate that as well. Finally, I'd segment things about the same way -- i.e., have one class that just manages a vector with a fixed lower bound of zero, and a second class that just deals with the offset to indices necessary for a non-zero lower bound.

Comment: He wouldnt allow that. The meaning of this class is to build the data structures from the ground, not using STL or anything that is non primitive.